# rendering state elements in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state called `changedFields` which is a list that contains the changed field when editing data.

```
        <Dialog
          open={this.state.isDialogOpen}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
          aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
        >
          <DialogTitle 
            id="responsive-dialog-title"
          >
            {'ARE YOU SURE YOU WISH TO MAKE THESE CHANGES?'}
          </DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <DialogContentText>
              <td style={{ 'font-weight': 'bold', 'border-bottom': '0px', 'margin-right': '2em' }}>You changed:</td>
              <td>
                <tr>{this.state.changedFields}</tr>
              </td>

            </DialogContentText>
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary">
              DISCARD CHANGES
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary" autoFocus>
              YES, KEEP CHANGES
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
```

I wrote the dialog this way. This looks like:

[image]

I am trying to put each element `description`, `trelloURL`, and `slackChannel` in different rows, but this just puts every elements in one line without a space.

How do I have to render it if I want to put them in different rows?

Comment: Please post the relevant component which has the changeFields state too.

Comment: the structure is `<tr>` -> `<td>` -> content. `<tr>` is a table row, `<td>` is table data, or a single cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you're just doing this:

```
<tr>{this.state.changedFields}</tr>
```

...which will use React's default "convert this array to string" and just output the elements one after another.

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = {
      changedFields: [
        "description",
        "trelloUrl",
        "slackChannel"
      ]
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>{this.state.changedFields}</tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

You need to do something to create the line breaks you want; perhaps separate rows:

One option is to put them each in their own row:

```
{this.state.changedFields.map(field => <tr><td>{field}</td></tr>)}
```

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = {
      changedFields: [
        "description",
        "trelloUrl",
        "slackChannel"
      ]
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
              {this.state.changedFields.map(field => <tr><td>{field}</td></tr>)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Or if appropriate, put it in one `td` using multiple `div`s since they default to `display: block` (or any other element and set its styling appropriately):

```
<tr><td>{this.state.changedFields.map(field => <div>{field}</div>)}</td></tr>
```

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = {
      changedFields: [
        "description",
        "trelloUrl",
        "slackChannel"
      ]
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>{this.state.changedFields.map(field => <div>{field}</div>)}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

---

You've now said you want them next to `You changed`, not in different rows. That's even simpler: Just put them in the same `td`:

```
<td style={{ 'font-weight': 'bold', 'border-bottom': '0px', 'padding-right': '2em' }}>You changed:</td>
<td>{this.state.changedFields.join(" ")}</td>
```

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = {
      changedFields: [
        "description",
        "trelloUrl",
        "slackChannel"
      ]
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style={{ 'font-weight': 'bold', 'border-bottom': '0px', 'padding-right': '2em' }}>You changed:</td>
            <td>{this.state.changedFields.join(" ")}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Side note: Strongly recommend using a class or similar and CSS, rather than inline stylings.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Do you mind if I ask an additional question? I tried to changed the style of `tr` to give some margin between two columns, but both inline styling and using styles.css didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @Dawn17 - See the updated answer, I didn't realize until I went back to add a live example (which I haven't finished yet) that you didn't include any `td`. You need to put text in a table row within a cell, if you don't it gets moved to in front of or after the table.

Comment: Or `<tr>{this.state.changedFields.map(field => <td>{field}</td>}</tr>`

Comment: @ChrisG - Yes, but the OP did say they wanted them listed on separate "lines," whereas table cells will tend to be across rather than down.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right; in that case: `<tr><td>{this.state.changedFields.join('<br/>')}</td></tr>`

Comment: @ChrisG - That would render `description<br/>trelloUrl<br/>slackChannel` (literally, as text). React doesn't work with markup strings (unless you use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a way to put this list next to `You changed` and give some margin? When I tried inline-styling and styles.css it didn't work.

Comment: @Dawn17 - Sure, just output them with spaces in-between and use either `padding-right` on the previous `td` or `padding-left` on the `td` you put them in (`margin` doesn't work on `td`).

Comment: Thank you so much@

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You're right again, I'll shut up now ;)

Comment: @ChrisG - LOL, that wasn't the intention. :-)